# What will happen if I reach free limits in Google App Engine (GAE)?

Tags: google-app-engine

What will happen if I reach free limits in Google App Engine (GAE)? Will GAE force me to pay for this? Will GAE just stop handling my app requests?

Answer (score 3):

They will not make you pay, although its highly encouraged else your APP might go down or show an error/redirect to users until the next quota cycle (or your manual re-up).

> When an application consumes all of an allocated resource, the
>   resource becomes unavailable until the quota is replenished. This may
>   mean that your application will not work until the quota is
>   replenished.

More: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted